# Different behavior of OkHttp3 on Linux and Windows

Tags: java, okhttp

I have some code which works ok on windows platform, however, the code gives a different behavior on Linux.

I have used the following code to submit a request to an HTTP server to get some messages. what I have done as follows

> 1. deploy the code on my local windows machine, then trigger a request and get the server response.

parameters:

> {"articleid":"","endtime":"2019-10-29T18:00:00","starttime":"2019-10-29T16:00:00","areaid":"","title":"","pageIndex":"1"}

server response:

> {"result":1,"errorcode":"","message":"","pageindex":1,"nextpage":2,"pagesize":100,"data":[...
>   some data here ...]}

2. deploy the code on a Linux server, trigger the request with the same parameters in step 1, however, the server response is different.

parameters:

> {"articleid":"","endtime":"2019-10-29T18:00:00","starttime":"2019-10-29T16:00:00","areaid":"","title":"","pageIndex":"1"}

server response:

> {"result":1,"errorcode":"","message":"","pageindex":1,"nextpage":null,"pagesize":0,"data":[]}

We have looked through the code but can not find what causes the different behaviors.

I suppose there may exist one/some java class files with the same name in different jars, and windows/Linux load different class files then cause the problem, but after looking through the jar file, I also have no ideas. the okhttp related jar files are as following:

`okhttp-3.10.0.jar
okio-1.14.0.jar
netty-codec-http-4.1.31.Final.jar 
httpcore-nio-4.4.10.jar
httpcore-4.4.10.jar
httpclient-4.5.6.jar
httpasyncclient-4.1.4.jar`

```
 public static String okHttpPost(String requestUrl,Map<String,String> map,String orgId,String taskID) throws IOException {

        String exceptionMessage="";
        String responseResult="";

        try {
            FormBody.Builder newFormBody = new FormBody.Builder();
            Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
            for(String key:keys){
                newFormBody.add(key,map.get(key));
            }
            RequestBody body = newFormBody.build();
            log.info("server url : "+requestUrl+";paramters："+new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map));
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(requestUrl)
                    .post(body)
                    .build();

            Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
            Response response = call.execute();

            if (response.code() != 200) {
                exceptionMessage = "request failed, taskID：" + taskID + "orgid：" + orgId + "response mesage："+response.toString();

                log.info(exceptionMessage);
            }

            responseResult = response.body().string();
            log.info("server url : " + requestUrl + ", reponse messages："+responseResult);
            return responseResult;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (!responseResult.contains("token")) {
                    do some thing;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Can give any ideas on why the same code behaviors different on windows and Linux platform?
How to change the code to let it works well on Linux?

Comment: Use OkHttp’s logging interceptor? That can show you the full difference between each request.

Comment: Thanks Wilson, the OkHttps's loggin interceptor is very useful.

Comment: The problem resolved, the behavior is caused by some peculiar code logic on the server side, it has nothing related to the platform difference.